# Leetcode Problem submmission issue - How Many Numbers Are Smaller Than the Current Number , Array returned as blank

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Here is my code

Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().

```
int* smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize)
{
    int count=0;
    int cl[numsSize];
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        for (int j=0;j<numsSize;j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                if(nums[i]>nums[j])
                    count++;
            } 
        }
        cl[i]=count;
        printf("%d \t",cl[i]);
    }
    int *p=&cl[0];
    return p;
}
```

Output shows as:

```
Wrong Answer
Runtime: 0 ms

Your input
[8,1,2,2,3]

stdout
4   0   1   1   3   

Output
[]

Expected
[4,0,1,1,3]
```

I know I can sort it first, but I want to know why my array returned remains blank.
Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: The function returns the address of one element of a local array, which goes out of scope (and life). You note that the array must be obtained with `malloc`.

Comment: Really just the lifetime is relevant here, the scope isn't.

Answer (score 0):

replace this :

```
 int cl[numsSize];
```

with this :

```
int *cl = (int*) malloc (numsSize * sizeof (int));
```

And don't forget to free memory when you finish with the use of your data:

```
free (cl);
```